# Google Maps API v3.22 script error when dropping the little man onto a road

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Since the latest release (on Tuesday) of the Google Maps API, every time I drag the little man onto a road and drop it, I get a script error (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/22/7/intl/en_gb/util.js).  The Street View then displays fine - but there is no Address Control and therefore no way to exit from Street View!

A similar script error also happens when specifying v3.23 (the error is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/23/7/intl/en_gb/util.js instead)!

However, if I set the controlStyle to 'azteca' everything works fine.  As this setting will be removed in August, I'm keen to start using the latest version as soon as possible.

Can anyone help?

Here's some code:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #map_canvas { height: 100%; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&v=3.23"> </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function Initialize() {
            try{
                //google.maps.controlStyle = 'azteca';
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), { zoom: 13, center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.41347, -0.83518), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });
                return "";
            } catch (err) {
                return err.message;
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you uncomment the commented line all works fine (but with the old controls).

John

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The next poster has provided code pretty much the same as I am using!  I'm also implementing it inside a vb.net user control.

Comment: OK - so - the next poster's post was unceremoniously removed!

Here's some code:-

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it was "me too", which should be another question (or an edit to yours, but that would probably be over the line).

Comment: um, where are you calling your `Initialize` function from?  You don't seem to do it anywhere in the code in your question, nor specify it as a callback when loading the Google maps JS.

Comment: Um, I'm calling it from the vb.net user control!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pleased to say that I am now able to answer my own question!

This may be of use to the other poster (Mac21 was it) who was also having this same issue.

The vb.net WebBrowser control is the problem!

In the latest Frozen Release of the Google Maps API, they have stopped supporting IE8 (which is understandable!).  The WebBrowser control, by default, uses IE7 for its rendering.

Fortunately, there is a way to over-ride this behaviour by adding a value into a key in the registry.  Once this value is in place, the Google Maps API works a treat!

I can't claim any credit for the actual solution as I found it here https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version - so thanks to Rick Strahl!

Enjoy!

John